# Apache Camel: Weave does not work in Split. Why?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, split, apache-camel

I have the following XML DSL context definition in spring:

```
<beans>
    <camelContext>
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:foo"/>
            <split parallelProcessing="true">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
                <to uri="direct:bar"/>
            </split>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

In my test I'm trying to weave the `direct:bar` endpoint like so:

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        weaveByToString(".*direct:bar.*").replace().to("mock:bar");
    }
});
```

This successfully works. But when route is starts an exception is thrown saying `org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: direct:bar`.

Why?

May be camel does not support weaving inside split?

**Note:** Everything works just fine with following XML:

```
<beans>
    <camelContext>
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:dummy"/>
            <to uri="direct:bar"/>
        </route>

        <route>
            <from uri="direct:foo"/>
            <split parallelProcessing="true">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
                <to uri="direct:dummy"/>
            </split>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your error with the use case described using Camel 2.7. Here is my test that pass:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveByToString(".*direct:bar.*").replace().to("mock:bar");
        }
    });

    MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:bar");
    mock.expectedMessageCount(1);

    template.sendBody("direct:foo", "this is a test");

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

Starting the route using `camel:run` also start without throwing a `NoSuchBeanException`.